# To import class to JSP in Tomcat6

Tags: java, jsp, tomcat, import

I am working on an assignment that asked to implement a webapps on Tomcat6 server

In the jsp file

```
<%@ 
page language = "java" 
import = "org.me.webapps.Bookstore.TitlesBean, java.util.*" 
session = "true"
%>
<!-- begin document -->
<html xmlns = "http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<body>
<%-- begin JSP scriptlet to create list of books --%>
<%
  TitlesBean titlesBean = new TitlesBean();
  List titles = titlesBean.getTitles();
  BookBean currentBook;

  // store titles in session for further use
  session.setAttribute( "titles", titles );

 ....
```

I have run ant build which generate the TitlesBean.class file under 
/WEB-INF/classes/org/me/webapps/bookstore/

However, when i browse the jsp page, i got the error as follow, looks like the server cannot find or import the .class file

```
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: Unable to compile class for JSP: 

An error occurred at line: 6 in the generated java file
Only a type can be imported. org.me.webapps.bookstore.TitlesBean resolves to a package

An error occurred at line: 32 in the jsp file: /war/books2.jsp
TitlesBean cannot be resolved to a type
29:       
30:    <%-- begin JSP scriptlet to create list of books --%>
31:    <%
32:       TitlesBean titlesBean = new TitlesBean();
33:       List titles = titlesBean.getTitles();
34:       BookBean currentBook;
.....
```

the TitlesBean.java

```
// TitlesBean.java
// Class TitlesBean makes a database connection and retrieves
// the books from the database.
package org.me.webapps.bookstore;

// Java core packages
import java.io.*;
import java.sql.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.net.*;

public class TitlesBean implements Serializable {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 6723471178342776147L;
private Connection connection;
private PreparedStatement titlesQuery;

// construct TitlesBean object
public TitlesBean() {
    // attempt database connection and setup SQL statements
    try {
        URL myUrl = getClass().getResource("TitlesBean.class");

        System.out.println(getDatabasePath(myUrl.toString()));

        Class.forName("org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver");
        connection = DriverManager.getConnection( "jdbc:hsqldb:hsql://localhost/bookdb", "sa", "" );

        titlesQuery = connection
                .prepareStatement("SELECT isbn, title, editionNumber, "
                        + "copyright, publisherID, imageFile, price "
                        + "FROM titles ORDER BY title");
    }

    // process exceptions during database setup
    catch (SQLException sqlException) {
        sqlException.printStackTrace();
    }

    // process problems locating data source
    catch (Exception exception) {
        exception.printStackTrace();
    }
}

// return a List of BookBeans
public List<BookBean> getTitles() {
    List<BookBean> titlesList = new ArrayList<BookBean>();

    // obtain list of titles
    try {
        ResultSet results = titlesQuery.executeQuery();

        // get row data
        while (results.next()) {
            BookBean book = new BookBean();

            book.setISBN(results.getString("isbn"));
            book.setTitle(results.getString("title"));
            book.setEditionNumber(results.getInt("editionNumber"));
            book.setCopyright(results.getString("copyright"));
            book.setPublisherID(results.getInt("publisherID"));
            book.setImageFile(results.getString("imageFile"));
            book.setPrice(results.getDouble("price"));

            titlesList.add(book);
        }
    } catch (SQLException exception) {
        exception.printStackTrace();
    }

    return titlesList;
}

private String getDatabasePath(String classPath) {
    String path = "";
    String crtToken;

    StringTokenizer tokens = new StringTokenizer(classPath, "/");
    int num = tokens.countTokens();
    tokens.nextToken();

    for (int i = 1; i < num; i++) {
        crtToken = tokens.nextToken();
        if (crtToken.equals("classes")) {
            break;
        }
        path = path + crtToken + "\\";
    }

    return path;
}

// close statements and terminate database connection
protected void finalize() {
    // attempt to close database connection
    try {
        connection.close();
    }

    // process SQLException on close operation
    catch (SQLException sqlException) {
        sqlException.printStackTrace();
    }
}
}
```

The setting of tomcat should be fine as i can run some simple jsp file with loop or condition as far as they dont need to import. What else should i try?

Comment: i guess import in JSP should be`import="org.me.webapps.bookstore.TitlesBean"` you have capital `B` in Bookstore

Answer (score 0):

`TitlesBean` is located at  `org.me.webapps.bookstore` and on your jsp import, you've declared it as `org.me.webapps.Bookstore.TitlesBean`,  you have an uppercase letter B on your declaration on your jsp import. 
declare it like this

```
<%@ 
      page language = "java" 
      import = "org.me.webapps.bookstore.TitlesBean, java.util.*" 
      session = "true"
%>
```